# how to read all the values of a registry key with vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, registry

I have the following values in my registry

key:

**`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Accepted Documents\`**

values:

```
* -> application/msword
** -> application/vnd.ms-excel
*** -> application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
```

and so on

I'd like to know how to read all of them

with **`Wscript.Shell`**, **`RegRead`** I can only read one value, but I don't know the values in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I got it

I had to use wmi, like this:

```
option explicit

const HKLM = &H80000002

dim keyPath
keyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Accepted Documents"

dim reg

dim valueNames, types
dim value
dim i

  set reg = getObject( "Winmgmts:root\default:StdRegProv" )

  if reg.enumValues( HKLM, keyPath, valueNames, types ) = 0 then
    if isArray( valueNames ) then
      for i = 0 to UBound( valueNames )
        reg.getStringValue HKLM, keyPath, valueNames(i), value
        msgBox( valueNames(i) & "=" & value )
      next
    end if
  end if
```

saludos

sas