# how to fetch java home directory from registry for windows server system

Tags: java, registry

can any body tell me how to fetch java home directory on windows server system from registry. I have to fetch this for java product version(JRE)

Comment: Why don't you use `java -version`?

Comment: Have you set JAVA_HOME in System variables and included it in the path?

Comment: no I have to fetch this from vbscript (asp classic)

Comment: @aksappy no that will be on user machine, so I don't think he will set java home in environment variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Oracle documentation

[Oracle Page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html) -
Installing the JDK also installs a private JRE and optionally a public copy. The private JRE is required to run the tools included with the JDK. It has no registry settings and is contained entirely in a jre directory (typically at C:\Program Files\jdk1.7.0\jre) whose location is known only to the JDK. On the other hand, the public JRE can be used by other Java applications, is contained outside the JDK (typically at C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.7.0), is registered with the Windows registry (at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft), can be removed using Add/Remove Programs, might be registered with browsers, and might have the java.exe file copied to the Windows system directory (which would make it the default system Java platform)

For reading a registry key

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083748/how-to-read-all-the-values-of-a-registry-key-with-vbscript) [Link 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/04/11/how-to-read-a-registry-key-and-its-values.aspx) [Link 3](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/vbscript-systems-administrator/a-simple-way-to-read-the-registry-with-vbscript/)

Answer (score 1):

HI all I use below function to fetch current jre home directory

```
Private Function GetRegValueJava()
    dim WshShell, strVal,javaCurrVer,javahome
    strVal = ""
    javaCurrVer = "HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion"
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    strVal = WshShell.RegRead(javaCurrVer)
    javahome = "HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\"&strVal&"\JavaHome"
    GetRegValueJava = WshShell.RegRead(javahome)
    Set WshShell = nothing
End Function
```

It works Fine for me